# Ignore dot characters when logging in from a gmail account

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, login

Gmail allows dot characters in your email address, but ignores them when you send email to a Gmail address. So ex.ample@gmail.com and example@gmail.com are essentially the same email address. However, StackExchange treats these two email addresses as different addresses for the purpose of having a StackExchange account. So if you created your account under the name ex.ample@gmail.com , you cannot log in with example@gmail.com as your StackExchange account name.

I have a tendency to forget whether or not I used my dot character when I sign up for something, and I hate it when a website (1) uses email addresses as user IDs (a terrible practice, honestly) and (2) actually cares about dot characters. So it would be super cool if I could log in whether or not I put the dot character in my login email address.

I suspect that this is technically infeasible, but at least it will remind users to remember to use the proper email address when logging in.

Comment: It is possible that this is not the case for other mail providers, however. Maintaining a list of exceptions seems unnecessary; be consistent with your e-mail address, or authenticate using your Google Account. (This uses OpenID, which is by far a superior option.)

Comment: can you even authenticate with google if stackexchange already associates your account with an email address?

Comment: @smcg Yes. You can associate multiple OpenIDs with the same account. Which brings me to my question... are you talking about "logging in with Stack Exchange" or "logging in with Google" in your feature request?

Comment: "Logging in with Stack Exchange". Logging in with Google already allows this, so my request would bring it up to feature parity.

Comment: @Charmander: I'm not aware of *any* other e-mail providers that do this (though there could easily be some I don't know about).